# Tips while 'normalizing' databases

Tags: database, normalization

I would be grateful if someone wrote **how I should look for databases normalization errors** in databases AND in entity classes in any language.

I just would like to know **what is the most important** and **where should I look for possible errors** in classes - in DAOs, BEANS or wherever. What should I take into account - any conventions, schemes etc?

For any answer, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've read something about the normal forms, e.g. on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Then I guess you know something, but you are not sure why should you do that or what is really important.

For example, if you have a table that contains relations between persons, it should not contain names, just IDs. If you have e.g. a table of `patients` where there are columns `father_name` and `mother_name`, it's an example of non-normalized table causing troubles.

Let's say the mother changes her name - from this moment on, your database is in inconsistent state. You decide to add some cascade/trigger on this change and you get into even worse problem: You realize several people can have the same name.

That is basically the main reason for using IDs as keys, not some column that is not a unique identifier. There is much more to learn, I hope someone provides you a link to some tutorial, as this is not really Q/A stuff.

Another good reason for normalizing a table are sparse tables - tables where some columns rarely contain anything else than null. E.g., there are four types of some device, each has different properties that are left null on the other types. In this case, creating a table that holds the specific properties of each device type (even though it's just {0,1}:1 relation) is advisable.

Comment: Naturally @Vlasec I've read sth concerning normalizing dbs, and yes, I know sth about such relations and possible problems, **but now for example:**

I got to normalize someone's databases (actually entities in JPA). How should I get started with doing this? I generated all these databases to real form, so this could be also helping.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you need to think about the logical data model. Draw a diagram if there is none drawn yet. Type down the relations between them (1:n, m:n using a relation table, {0,1}:1). Think if something that is not declared to be `@NotNull` should actually be declared as such. Create some new tables for the nullable things. I added some info to the answer.